# Relationship between force and potential energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, potential-energy, conservative-field

Consider a conservative force $\vec{F}=F_1\hat{i}+F_2\hat{j}+F_3\hat{k}   $  acting through a displacement $\vec{ds} =dx\hat{i}+dy\hat{j}+dz\hat{k}$. The work done $dw$, will be equal to $F_{1}dx +F_{2}dy +F_{3}dz$. From the work-energy theorem, this is equal to the change in kinetic energy $dK$.

However, since the force is conservative, $K+U$ is constant, so $dK=-dU$ , where $U$ is the potential energy. So we have:
$$-dU=F_{1}dx +F_{2}dy +F_{3}dz$$

From multivariable calculus, we know that $dU=\frac{\partial U}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial U}{\partial y} dy + \frac{\partial U}{\partial z} dz$. We thus have:

$(-F_{1})dx+(-F_{2})dy+(-F_{3})dz=\frac{\partial U}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial U}{\partial y} dy + \frac{\partial U}{\partial z} dz$.

Comparing , we *can* conclude that $F_{1}=-\frac{\partial U}{\partial x},F_{2}=-\frac{\partial U}{\partial y}$ and $F_{3}=-\frac{\partial U}{\partial z}$, which further implies,
$$\vec{F}=-\nabla{U}$$.

**Question:**

Now my worry is that the "comparing" step doesn't seem to be rigorous at all. Am I just being pedantic? And if it is indeed non-rigorous/wrong, how do we reach the conclusion from there?

Comment: K + U isn't constant in this case because the force is acting through a distance, is doing work, and is adding kinetic energy to the object it is being applied to.

Comment: @David White. If the force is conservative, then $K+U$ is indeed a constant.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with making the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

As far I can see there is no non-rigorous thing in comparing besides the proof can be made shorter.

---

The work is done by a conservative force $\mathbf{F}$ around a closed path is zero.
$$\oint \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}=0$$
Using the [stokes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem), We conclude that
$$\nabla \times \mathbf{F}=0$$
which imply that
$$\mathbf{F}=-\nabla U$$

---

Comment: As it turns out, $\nabla \times \vec F =0$ is not enough to garauntee that $\vec F$ is *exact*, i.e. $\vec F=-\nabla U$. The region of space to which Stoke's theorem is applied must be contractible.  For example, it is possible to find vector fields on three dimensional Euclidean space minus the z-axis, that have vanishing curl and yet are not the gradient of a scalar function.

Answer (score 2):

with

$$T=\frac{m}{2}(\dot x^2+\dot y^2+\dot z^2)$$
and

$$U=U(x,y,z)$$
you can obtain the equation of motion with Euler-Lagrange

$$m{\ddot x}+{\frac {\partial }{\partial x}}U \left( x,y,z \right)=0 $$

$$m{\ddot y}+{\frac {\partial }{\partial y}}U \left( x,y,z \right)=0 $$

$$m{\ddot z}+{\frac {\partial }{\partial z}}U \left( x,y,z \right)=0 $$

according to NEWTON second law

$$m\,{\ddot x}=F_x$$
$$m\,{\ddot y}=F_y$$
$$m\,{\ddot z}=F_z$$

thus

$$F_x=-{\frac {\partial }{\partial x}}U \left( x,y,z \right)$$

$$F_y=-{\frac {\partial }{\partial y}}U \left( x,y,z \right)$$

$$F_z=-{\frac {\partial }{\partial z}}U \left( x,y,z \right)$$

Answer (score 0):

If by conservative force, it means that there is a scalar function U, such that:

$-dU =F_xdx + F_ydy + F_zdz$

the conclusion is mandatory, I see no problem.

Of course it is always possible to write:
$\Delta w = \mathbf {F.dx} =  F_xdx + F_ydy + F_zdz$ even for non conservative forces. But here $\Delta w$ is not the differential of a function, but only the result of a scalar product.

Answer (score 0):

For any scaler differentiable function $g(\vec{r})$ $$\mathrm{d}g = \nabla g \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{r}.$$

So $\mathrm{d} U = \nabla U \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{r}$.

If $\mathrm{d} U = -\vec{F} \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{r}$, for a conservative force, then $\nabla U$ must be identical to $-\vec{F}$